# Is there a way to interpolate series with recurring values using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to interpolate a x/y series using `matplotlib`. The problem I am facing is that `spline` and `interp1d` fail because I have recurring values in both the x and y arrays.

I have tried using the spline and `interp1d` functions from `scipy`, but both fail because of the recurring values issue

```py
x1 = [0.82 0.82 0.82 0.82 0.82 0.82 0.83 0.83 0.83 0.83 0.83 0.83 0.83]
y1 = [0.93 0.93 0.93 0.93 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94 0.94]
f = interp1d(x1, y1, kind='cubic')   #this gives an error: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.



#another thing I tried

xnew = np.linspace(x1.min(),x1.max(),300)
splined = spline(x1,y1,xnew)    #this gives an error: Matrix is singular
```

I am expecting the interpolated y value to gradually increase with the increase of x. So for example, the corresponding y value for x = 0.82 would be 0.931, 0.932, etc. My goal in the end is to get a smooth curve.

Comment: What do you expect the interpolated result to be? For example, what value should you get for x = 0.82?

Comment: What's your expected output from the above two series?

Comment: I am expecting the interpolated y value to gradually increase with the increase of x. So for example, the corresponding y value for x = 0.82 would be 0.931, 0.932, etc. My goal in the end is to get a smooth curve.

Comment: @user10664643. In context of your data your explanation is meaningless. Please provide a concrete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a polynomial?

```
np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1, y1, 2))(new_x) # 2 for second degree
```

Comment: That's fitting, not interpolation.